# What is a good translation for the "overview" other than "síntesis"?

Tags: traducción, selección-de-palabras

I am looking for a good translation that doesn't sound too technical. I read the definition of "**síntesis**" and found the word "**compendio**" which has a definition which seems to match "overview" well, but I am unsure how common this word is used in everyday speech. I am really looking for a word that a grade school student would know. Any ideas? Do any other words come to mind?

Comment: What are you overviewing? Context is everything in language.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It depends a lot on the context, but as you mention *síntesis* and *compendio*, a word that is commonly used and has similar meaning is **resumen**.

Other expressions to have in mind: *panorama*, *introducción*, *introducción general*, *plan de la charla*.

Comment: I agree with rsanchez, "**resumen**" is better.

Comment: I would add "visión general (sobre algo)".

Comment: Or "**revisión**"